# Remove all log files except current log file

Tags: linux, command-line, files, find

My sip server generates 3 log files for each hour:

`Progress-23May2017-10-00hrs.log
 Call-23May2017-10-00hrs.log
 Error-23May2017-10-00hrs.log`

So I need to delete all other log files except the current hour log.
I tried with this command

```
 find . -type f -name "*-23May2017-10-00hrs.log" -print
```

it printed my current time's three log files.

so when I tried this command to verify files not matching the current time log.

```
find . -type f -name "!(*-23May2017-10-30hrs.log)" -print
```

it gives me nothing.

How to get my other log files deleted?

Comment: What SIP server is it? Doesn't it implement some sort of log rotation to do this for you?

Comment: Use `logrotate` for that job.

Comment: @Thomas it generates log for each hour but i use this sip server for my development purposes thats the reason

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/fi -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* -type f -mmin +1800 | sort | head -n -1 | xargs rm
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your find processes are not escaped, so that the wildcards `*` are transformed. 
To prevent that you can either use backslashes `\` or use single-quotes `'`

So: 
`find . -type f -name '*-23May2017-10-00hrs.log' -print`
should work fine.

Back to your real questions: 
There are several ways to solve that. First you can use find's `-mtime` feature to just listen every file which last modification is x minutes ago. 
Let's assume your sip server logs at `/var/log/sip/`

`find /var/log/sip/ -type f -name '*.log' -mmin +$((24*60)) -print` 
will show you every file ending with `.log` and which last modification was 24*60 minutes (1 day) ago.

However you can also use a tool which is made for logging handling and thats `logrotate`.

logrotate is available on every major unix distribution and allows you to compress files at a certain age, remove them at another ago and so on. The feature list is quite long. 
It's easy to install, runs as a daemon and you don't have to fiddle around with extra cronjobs.

My suggestions is to use logrotate. Check out it's simplicity at: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate